# Does propagation delay in an opto isolator sum with switching time in a FET?

Tags: mosfet, opto-isolator

Optoisolators such as the Vishay VO3120 list a "propagation time delay time" of 0.4 microseconds. Common FETs such as the IRFZ44N list a "Turn-On Delay Time" of 12 nanoseconds.

Normally I use the turn on/off times of a transistor to determine the maximum permissible switching frequency for the component, as well as the appropriate dead time.

When doing such calculation for a FET driven through an optoisolator do I need to sum the values from both datasheets? Or does the signal from an optoisolator just get time shifted? If the signal is time shifted, can I ignore the time shift if all switching components are driven through equivalent optoisolators?

Datasheets:
http://www.vishay.com/docs/81314/vo3120.pdf
http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irfz44n.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153563b3575220b

Comment: The tpd value is not specified as 0.400 µs but 0.4 µs. And 0.4 + 0.012 ≈ 0.4. You are overthinking this.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, the delay is summed as well the propagation times, like rise fall. If you need very high switching frequency, then optocouplers may not be the good option. MAny applications use IR21xx gate drivers without galvanic separation, or you can use pulse transformers, or magnetic couplers instead of optocouplers. In your case you have tr and tf 100ns, which will determine the of switching loss, the propagation delay can be taken into account to set proper trigger delay, to avoid the cros conduction.

Or perhaps you want to acheive nonreasonable high switching frequency, please explain what is the device used for.

This is a cheap alternative used in many welders op to 50kHz (DT<50%).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f32BM0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the example circuit. I did some more reading. If I understand this circuit, it is meant to be driven continuously to keep the gate charged. When the current stops, D2 is reverse biased. Then Q2 is saturated and quickly discharges the gate. Do I have this correct?

Comment: @EricUrban It is a driver circuit for forward converter where duty cycle is limited to 50% (I think). The pulse transformer is usually 1:1; primary driving voltage is 15V. The transformer has the parameter of voltage integral Vs, the max. pulse length[s] x max. primary voltage may not exceed rated. Example 50khz, 15V, DT50%: 15V*0.5*1/50000= 150 Vus.  You are right about discharging.

Answer (score 0):

I think this depends on how the outputs of this circuit are used.

If this is a digital cycle path then yes, you must consider all of it.

If this uses feedback, then yes you need to consider all of it (or at least the feedback loops -- they must be able to settle within the cycle time).

If it is just an open loop path then you can drive it using the maximum delay element as the limiting factor.  However the outputs from this circuit will not necessarily be 'in the same cycle' as the inputs, if your total delay exceeds the cycle time.